# Error NoopPersistenceManager java.lang.AssertionError: hardAssert failed Firebase Unity

Tags: android, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

Android mobile crashes when trying to set priority.
The issue doesn't occur with IOS, or Unity editor.
I'm not sure how to avoid the crash, and I don't see any updates for Firebase SDK related persistence issues.

Unity editor version: 2020.1.11f1 Firebase Unity SDK version: 6.16.1

`FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.RootReference.Child("users").Child(num).SetPriorityAsync(pir);`

Error:

`2021/01/31 15:14:06.812 23466 23582 Error NoopPersistenceManager Caught Throwable.`

`2021/01/31 15:14:06.812 23466 23582 Error NoopPersistenceManager java.lang.AssertionError: hardAssert failed:`

```
2021/01/31 15:14:06.812 23466 23582 Error NoopPersistenceManager    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.Utilities.hardAssert(Utilities.java:234)
2021/01/31 15:14:06.812 23466 23582 Error NoopPersistenceManager    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.Utilities.hardAssert(Utilities.java:229)
2021/01/31 15:14:06.812 23466 23582 Error NoopPersistenceManager    at com.google.firebase.database.snapshot.ChildrenNode.updateChild(ChildrenNode.java:293)
2021/01/31 15:14:06.812 23466 23582 Error NoopPersistenceManager    at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.ViewProcessor.applyServerOverwrite(ViewProcessor.java:319)
2021/01/31 15:14:06.812 23466 23582 Error NoopPersistenceManager    at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.ViewProcessor.applyOperation(ViewProcessor.java:90)
2021/01/31 15:14:06.812 23466 23582 Error NoopPersistenceManager    at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.View.applyOperation(View.java:173)
2021/01/31 15:14:06.812 23466 23582 Error NoopPersistenceManager    at com.google.firebase.database.core.SyncPoint.applyOperationToView(SyncPoint.java:78)
2021/01/31 15:14:06.812 23466 23582 Error NoopPersistenceManager    at com.google.firebase.database.core.SyncPoint.applyOperation(SyncPoint.java:109)
2021/01/31 15:14:06.812 23466 23582 Error NoopPersistenceManager    at com.google.firebase.database.core.SyncTree.applyOperationHelper(SyncTree.java:925)
2021/01/31 15:14:06.812 23466 23582 Error NoopPersistenceManager    at com.google.firebase.database.core.SyncTree.applyOperationHelper(SyncTree.java:920)
2021/01/31 15:14:06.812 23466 23582 Error NoopPersistenceManager    at com.google.firebase.database.core.SyncTree.applyOperationHelper(SyncTree.java:920)
2021/01/31 15:14:06.812 23466 23582 Error NoopPersistenceManager    at com.google.firebase.database.core.SyncTree.applyOperationHelper(SyncTree.java:920)
2021/01/31 15:14:06.812 23466 23582 Error NoopPersistenceManager    at com.google.firebase.database.core.SyncTree.applyOperationHelper(SyncTree.java:920)
2021/01/31 15:14:06.812 23466 23582 Error NoopPersistenceManager    at com.google.firebase.database.core.SyncTree.applyOperationToSyncPoints(SyncTree.java:887)
2021/01/31 15:14:06.812 23466 23582 Error NoopPersistenceManager    at com.google.firebase.database.core.SyncTree.access$400(SyncTree.java:76)
2021/01/31 15:14:06.812 23466 23582 Error NoopPersistenceManager    at com.google.firebase.database.core.SyncTree$5.call(SyncTree.java:303)
2021/01/31 15:14:06.812 23466 23582 Error NoopPersistenceManager    at com.google.firebase.database.core.SyncTree$5.call(SyncTree.java:299)
2021/01/31 15:14:06.812 23466 23582 Error NoopPersistenceManager    at com.google.firebase.database.core.persistence.NoopPersistenceManager.runInTransaction(NoopPersistenceManager.java:126)
2021/01/31 15:14:06.812 23466 23582 Error NoopPersistenceManager    at com.google.firebase.database.core.SyncTree.applyServerOverwrite(SyncTree.java:298)
2021/01/31 15:14:06.812 23466 23582 Error NoopPersistenceManager    at com.google.firebase.database.core.Repo.onDataUpdate(Repo.java:342)
2021/01/31 15:14:06.812 23466 23582 Error NoopPersistenceManager    at com.google.firebase.database.connection.PersistentConnectionImpl.onDataPush(PersistentConnectionImpl.java:782)
2021/01/31 15:14:06.812 23466 23582 Error NoopPersistenceManager    at com.google.firebase.database.connection.PersistentConnectionImpl.onDataMessage(PersistentConnectionImpl.java:415)
2021/01/31 15:14:06.812 23466 23582 Error NoopPersistenceManager    at com.google.firebase.database.connection.Connection.onDataMessage(Connection.java:164)
2021/01/31 15:14:06.812 23466 23582 Error NoopPersistenceManager    at com.google.firebase.database.connection.Connection.onMessage(Connection.java:128)
2021/01/31 15:14:06.812 23466 23582 Error NoopPersistenceManager    at com.google.firebase.database.connection.WebsocketConnection.appendFrame(WebsocketConnection.java:257)
2021/01/31 15:14:06.812 23466 23582 Error NoopPersistenceManager    at com.google.firebase.database.connection.WebsocketConnection.handleIncomingFrame(WebsocketConnection.java:304)
2021/01/31 15:14:06.812 23466 23582 Error NoopPersistenceManager    at com.google.firebase.database.connection.WebsocketConnection.access$500(WebsocketConnection.java:34)
2021/01/31 15:14:06.812 23466 23582 Error NoopPersistenceManager    at com.google.firebase.database.connection.WebsocketConnection$WSClientTubesock$2.run(WebsocketConnection.java:86)
2021/01/31 15:14:06.812 23466 23582 Error NoopPersistenceManager    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:459)
2021/01/31 15:14:06.812 23466 23582 Error NoopPersistenceManager    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
2021/01/31 15:14:06.812 23466 23582 Error NoopPersistenceManager    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301)
2021/01/31 15:14:06.812 23466 23582 Error NoopPersistenceManager    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
2021/01/31 15:14:06.812 23466 23582 Error NoopPersistenceManager    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
2021/01/31 15:14:06.812 23466 23582 Error NoopPersistenceManager    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
2021/01/31 15:14:06.814 23466 23582 Error RunLoop Uncaught exception in Firebase Database runloop (19.4.0). If you are not already on the latest version of the Firebase SDKs, try updating your dependencies. Should this problem persist, please file a report at https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk
2021/01/31 15:14:06.814 23466 23582 Error RunLoop java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.AssertionError: hardAssert failed: 
2021/01/31 15:14:06.814 23466 23582 Error RunLoop   at com.google.firebase.database.core.persistence.NoopPersistenceManager.runInTransaction(NoopPersistenceManager.java:131)
2021/01/31 15:14:06.814 23466 23582 Error RunLoop   at com.google.firebase.database.core.SyncTree.applyServerOverwrite(SyncTree.java:298)
2021/01/31 15:14:06.814 23466 23582 Error RunLoop   at com.google.firebase.database.core.Repo.onDataUpdate(Repo.java:342)
2021/01/31 15:14:06.814 23466 23582 Error RunLoop   at com.google.firebase.database.connection.PersistentConnectionImpl.onDataPush(PersistentConnectionImpl.java:782)
2021/01/31 15:14:06.814 23466 23582 Error RunLoop   at com.google.firebase.database.connection.PersistentConnectionImpl.onDataMessage(PersistentConnectionImpl.java:415)
2021/01/31 15:14:06.814 23466 23582 Error RunLoop   at com.google.firebase.database.connection.Connection.onDataMessage(Connection.java:164)
2021/01/31 15:14:06.814 23466 23582 Error RunLoop   at com.google.firebase.database.connection.Connection.onMessage(Connection.java:128)
2021/01/31 15:14:06.814 23466 23582 Error RunLoop   at com.google.firebase.database.connection.WebsocketConnection.appendFrame(WebsocketConnection.java:257)
2021/01/31 15:14:06.814 23466 23582 Error RunLoop   at com.google.firebase.database.connection.WebsocketConnection.handleIncomingFrame(WebsocketConnection.java:304)
2021/01/31 15:14:06.814 23466 23582 Error RunLoop   at com.google.firebase.database.connection.WebsocketConnection.access$500(WebsocketConnection.java:34)
2021/01/31 15:14:06.814 23466 23582 Error RunLoop   at com.google.firebase.database.connection.WebsocketConnection$WSClientTubesock$2.run(WebsocketConnection.java:86)
2021/01/31 15:14:06.814 23466 23582 Error RunLoop   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:459)
2021/01/31 15:14:06.814 23466 23582 Error RunLoop   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
2021/01/31 15:14:06.814 23466 23582 Error RunLoop   at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301)
2021/01/31 15:14:06.814 23466 23582 Error RunLoop   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
2021/01/31 15:14:06.814 23466 23582 Error RunLoop   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
2021/01/31 15:14:06.814 23466 23582 Error RunLoop   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
2021/01/31 15:14:06.814 23466 23582 Error RunLoop Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError: hardAssert failed: 
2021/01/31 15:14:06.814 23466 23582 Error RunLoop   at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.Utilities.hardAssert(Utilities.java:234)
2021/01/31 15:14:06.814 23466 23582 Error RunLoop   at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.Utilities.hardAssert(Utilities.java:229)
2021/01/31 15:14:06.814 23466 23582 Error RunLoop   at com.google.firebase.database.snapshot.ChildrenNode.updateChild(ChildrenNode.java:293)
2021/01/31 15:14:06.814 23466 23582 Error RunLoop   at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.ViewProcessor.applyServerOverwrite(ViewProcessor.java:319)
2021/01/31 15:14:06.814 23466 23582 Error RunLoop   at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.ViewProcessor.applyOperation(ViewProcessor.java:90)
2021/01/31 15:14:06.814 23466 23582 Error RunLoop   at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.View.applyOperation(View.java:173)
2021/01/31 15:14:06.814 23466 23582 Error RunLoop   at com.google.firebase.database.core.SyncPoint.applyOperationToView(SyncPoint.java:78)
2021/01/31 15:14:06.814 23466 23582 Error RunLoop   at com.google.firebase.database.core.SyncPoint.applyOperation(SyncPoint.java:109)
2021/01/31 15:14:06.814 23466 23582 Error RunLoop   at com.google.firebase.database.core.SyncTree.applyOperationHelper(SyncTree.java:925)
2021/01/31 15:14:06.814 23466 23582 Error RunLoop   at com.google.firebase.database.core.SyncTree.applyOperationHelper(SyncTree.java:920)
2021/01/31 15:14:06.814 23466 23582 Error RunLoop   at com.google.firebase.database.core.SyncTree.applyOperationHelper(SyncTree.java:920)
2021/01/31 15:14:06.814 23466 23582 Error RunLoop   at com.google.firebase.database.core.SyncTree.applyOperationHelper(SyncTree.java:920)
2021/01/31 15:14:06.814 23466 23582 Error RunLoop   at com.google.firebase.database.core.SyncTree.applyOperationHelper(SyncTree.java:920)
2021/01/31 15:14:06.814 23466 23582 Error RunLoop   at com.google.firebase.database.core.SyncTree.applyOperationToSyncPoints(SyncTree.java:887)
2021/01/31 15:14:06.814 23466 23582 Error RunLoop   at com.google.firebase.database.core.SyncTree.access$400(SyncTree.java:76)
2021/01/31 15:14:06.814 23466 23582 Error RunLoop   at com.google.firebase.database.core.SyncTree$5.call(SyncTree.java:303)
2021/01/31 15:14:06.814 23466 23582 Error RunLoop   at com.google.firebase.database.core.SyncTree$5.call(SyncTree.java:299)
2021/01/31 15:14:06.814 23466 23582 Error RunLoop   at com.google.firebase.database.core.persistence.NoopPersistenceManager.runInTransaction(NoopPersistenceManager.java:126)
2021/01/31 15:14:06.814 23466 23582 Error RunLoop   ... 16 more
2021/01/31 15:14:06.816 23466 23466 Debug AndroidRuntime Shutting down VM
0001/01/01 00:00:00.000 -1 -1 Info  --------- beginning of crash
2021/01/31 15:14:06.818 23466 23466 Error AndroidRuntime FATAL EXCEPTION: main
2021/01/31 15:14:06.818 23466 23466 Error AndroidRuntime Process: com.fff.fff PID: 23466
2021/01/31 15:14:06.818 23466 23466 Error AndroidRuntime java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncaught exception in Firebase Database runloop (19.4.0). If you are not already on the latest version of the Firebase SDKs, try updating your dependencies. Should this problem persist, please file a report at https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk
2021/01/31 15:14:06.818 23466 23466 Error AndroidRuntime    at com.google.firebase.database.android.AndroidPlatform$1$1.run(AndroidPlatform.java:96)
2021/01/31 15:14:06.818 23466 23466 Error AndroidRuntime    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
2021/01/31 15:14:06.818 23466 23466 Error AndroidRuntime    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
2021/01/31 15:14:06.818 23466 23466 Error AndroidRuntime    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
2021/01/31 15:14:06.818 23466 23466 Error AndroidRuntime    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7073)
2021/01/31 15:14:06.818 23466 23466 Error AndroidRuntime    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
2021/01/31 15:14:06.818 23466 23466 Error AndroidRuntime    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
2021/01/31 15:14:06.818 23466 23466 Error AndroidRuntime    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:964)
2021/01/31 15:14:06.818 23466 23466 Error AndroidRuntime Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.AssertionError: hardAssert failed: 
2021/01/31 15:14:06.818 23466 23466 Error AndroidRuntime    at com.google.firebase.database.core.persistence.NoopPersistenceManager.runInTransaction(NoopPersistenceManager.java:131)
2021/01/31 15:14:06.818 23466 23466 Error AndroidRuntime    at com.google.firebase.database.core.SyncTree.applyServerOverwrite(SyncTree.java:298)
2021/01/31 15:14:06.818 23466 23466 Error AndroidRuntime    at com.google.firebase.database.core.Repo.onDataUpdate(Repo.java:342)
2021/01/31 15:14:06.818 23466 23466 Error AndroidRuntime    at com.google.firebase.database.connection.PersistentConnectionImpl.onDataPush(PersistentConnectionImpl.java:782)
2021/01/31 15:14:06.818 23466 23466 Error AndroidRuntime    at com.google.firebase.database.connection.PersistentConnectionImpl.onDataMessage(PersistentConnectionImpl.java:415)
2021/01/31 15:14:06.818 23466 23466 Error AndroidRuntime    at com.google.firebase.database.connection.Connection.onDataMessage(Connection.java:164)
2021/01/31 15:14:06.818 23466 23466 Error AndroidRuntime    at com.google.firebase.database.connection.Connection.onMessage(Connection.java:128)
2021/01/31 15:14:06.818 23466 23466 Error AndroidRuntime    at com.google.firebase.database.connection.WebsocketConnection.appendFrame(WebsocketConnection.java:257)
2021/01/31 15:14:06.818 23466 23466 Error AndroidRuntime    at com.google.firebase.database.connection.WebsocketConnection.handleIncomingFrame(WebsocketConnection.java:304)
2021/01/31 15:14:06.818 23466 23466 Error AndroidRuntime    at com.google.firebase.database.connection.WebsocketConnection.access$500(WebsocketConnection.java:34)
2021/01/31 15:14:06.818 23466 23466 Error AndroidRuntime    at com.google.firebase.database.connection.WebsocketConnection$WSClientTubesock$2.run(WebsocketConnection.java:86)
2021/01/31 15:14:06.818 23466 23466 Error AndroidRuntime    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:459)
2021/01/31 15:14:06.818 23466 23466 Error AndroidRuntime    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
2021/01/31 15:14:06.818 23466 23466 Error AndroidRuntime    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301)
2021/01/31 15:14:06.818 23466 23466 Error AndroidRuntime    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
2021/01/31 15:14:06.818 23466 23466 Error AndroidRuntime    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
2021/01/31 15:14:06.818 23466 23466 Error AndroidRuntime    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
2021/01/31 15:14:06.818 23466 23466 Error AndroidRuntime Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError: hardAssert failed: 
2021/01/31 15:14:06.818 23466 23466 Error AndroidRuntime    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.Utilities.hardAssert(Utilities.java:234)
2021/01/31 15:14:06.818 23466 23466 Error AndroidRuntime    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.Utilities.hardAssert(Utilities.java:229)
2021/01/31 15:14:06.818 23466 23466 Error AndroidRuntime    at com.google.firebase.database.snapshot.ChildrenNode.updateChild(ChildrenNode.java:293)
2021/01/31 15:14:06.818 23466 23466 Error AndroidRuntime    at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.ViewProcessor.applyServerOverwrite(ViewProcessor.java:319)
2021/01/31 15:14:06.818 23466 23466 Error AndroidRuntime    at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.ViewProcessor.applyOperation(ViewProcessor.java:90)
2021/01/31 15:14:06.818 23466 23466 Error AndroidRuntime    at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.View.applyOperation(View.java:173)
2021/01/31 15:14:06.818 23466 23466 Error AndroidRuntime    at com.google.firebase.database.core.SyncPoint.applyOperationToView(SyncPoint.java:78)
2021/01/31 15:14:06.818 23466 23466 Error AndroidRuntime    at com.google.firebase.database.core.SyncPoint.applyOperation(SyncPoint.java:109)
2021/01/31 15:14:06.818 23466 23466 Error AndroidRuntime    at com.google.firebase.database.core.SyncTree.applyOperationHelper(SyncTree.java:925)
2021/01/31 15:14:06.818 23466 23466 Error AndroidRuntime    at com.google.firebase.database.core.SyncTree.applyOperationHelper(SyncTree.java:920)
2021/01/31 15:14:06.818 23466 23466 Error AndroidRuntime    at com.google.firebase.database.core.SyncTree.applyOperationHelper(SyncTree.java:920)
2021/01/31 15:14:06.818 23466 23466 Error AndroidRuntime    at com.google.firebase.database.core.SyncTree.applyOperationHelper(SyncTree.java:920)
2021/01/31 15:14:06.818 23466 23466 Error AndroidRuntime    at com.google.firebase.database.core.SyncTree.applyOperationHelper(SyncTree.java:920)
2021/01/31 15:14:06.818 23466 23466 Error AndroidRuntime    at com.google.firebase.database.core.SyncTree.applyOperationToSyncPoints(SyncTree.java:887)
2021/01/31 15:14:06.818 23466 23466 Error AndroidRuntime    at com.google.firebase.database.core.SyncTree.access$400(SyncTree.java:76)
2021/01/31 15:14:06.818 23466 23466 Error AndroidRuntime    at com.google.firebase.database.core.SyncTree$5.call(SyncTree.java:303)
2021/01/31 15:14:06.818 23466 23466 Error AndroidRuntime    at com.google.firebase.database.core.SyncTree$5.call(SyncTree.java:299)
2021/01/31 15:14:06.818 23466 23466 Error AndroidRuntime    at com.google.firebase.database.core.persistence.NoopPersistenceManager.runInTransaction(NoopPersistenceManager.java:126)
2021/01/31 15:14:06.818 23466 23466 Error AndroidRuntime    ... 16 more
```

`

Unity editor version: 2020.1.11f1
Firebase Unity SDK version: 6.16.1
My dependencies:

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
// Android Resolver Dependencies Start
implementation 'com.google.ads.mediation:inmobi:9.1.0.0' // Assets/GoogleMobileAds/Editor/InMobiMediationDependencies.xml:7
implementation 'com.google.ads.mediation:mopub:5.10.0.0' // Assets/GoogleMobileAds/Editor/MoPubMediationDependencies.xml:8
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.3.0' // Assets/GoogleMobileAds/Editor/GoogleMobileAdsDependencies.xml:7
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.4.0' // Assets/Firebase/Editor/AppDependencies.xml:17
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.5.0' // Assets/Firebase/Editor/StorageDependencies.xml:15
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-app-unity:6.16.1' // Assets/Firebase/Editor/AppDependencies.xml:22
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.3.2' // Assets/Firebase/Editor/AuthDependencies.xml:13
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-unity:6.16.1' // Assets/Firebase/Editor/AuthDependencies.xml:20
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-common:19.3.1' // Assets/Firebase/Editor/AppDependencies.xml:13
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.4.0' // Assets/Firebase/Editor/DatabaseDependencies.xml:13
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database-unity:6.16.1' // Assets/Firebase/Editor/DatabaseDependencies.xml:20
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-functions:19.1.0' // Assets/Firebase/Editor/FunctionsDependencies.xml:13
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-functions-unity:6.16.1' // Assets/Firebase/Editor/FunctionsDependencies.xml:20
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:19.2.0' // Assets/Firebase/Editor/StorageDependencies.xml:13
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage-unity:6.16.1' // Assets/Firebase/Editor/StorageDependencies.xml:20
// Android Resolver Dependencies End
```

Comment: This definitely seems like an SDK issue, so you should follow up on the GitHub issues page ( which I think this is you given the timestamp and similarities to your handle here, but I'll link it just in case: https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-unity/issues/945 ). I'll follow up over there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated the SDK to 7.0.2 no more error.